# Testing error in flutter- Failed Assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, flutter-test

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
```

//Home page

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  bool isSignedIn= false;
  PageController pageController;
  int getPageIndex=0;

  void initState() { 
    super.initState();

    pageController = PageController();

    gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSignInAccount){
      controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);
    },onError: (gError){
      print("Error Message"+gError);
    });
    gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors : false).then((gSignInAccount)
    {
      controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);

    }
    ).catchError((gError){
      print("Error Message"+gError);
    });
  }
```

//To SignIn the account

```
     controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) async
    {
    if(signInAccount != null)
    {
      await saveUserInfoToFireStore();
      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = true;
      });

    }
    else{
       setState(() {
        isSignedIn = false;
      });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: if(signInAccount != null)

Comment: I just see a wall of code without any stated question.  There's an error mentioned in the title, but you haven't provided the full error message and error details.

Comment: Where is signInAccount defined? You have not included it...

Comment: controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) - right here.